# why cant i call method from the class i created with generics? java

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently learning java, and I encountered a problem with generics that I can not solve.

So I have this class:

`public class EntityRepository <Entidade extends Entity>{ "code" }`
with this method:

---

```
public Long create(Entidade ent) {

    ent.setId(this.nextId());
    this.m1.put(ent.getId(), ent);
    return ent.getId();
}
```

---

and now i have another method in another class like this:

```
public static void subMenu(EntityRepository<? extends Entity> repository, String entidade)
```

### which has this code:

```
Entity item = new Entity();
if(entidade.equals("produto")){
    item = new Product();
}
else if(entidade.equals("prateleira")){
    item = new Shelf();
}
repository.create(item);
repository.printList(entidade);
```

---

so basically when String 'entidade' is equal to strings "produto" or "prateleira" it is supose to call the 'create' method from the first class I mentioned above but with either a 'Product' or a 'Shelf' as a parameter. (which are objects that extend to Entity)

my problem is that is that has this error:

"The method create(capture#1-of ? extends Entity) in the type EntityRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Entity)"

and i cant seem to understand why nor can i find any clues around the web...

can some one help me?
thanks!

Comment: replace `EntityRepository<? extends Entity> repository` with `EntityRepository<? super Entity> repository`

Comment: Short answer - because `EntityRepository` is generic, you could be dealing with an `EntityRepository<Xyz>` which means you'd have to pass an `Xyz` to `create`, instead of just a plain `Entity`.

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't actually be using generics here, since you expect `create` to accept any type of `Entity` as an argument.

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to follow if you followed the naming convention for generics parameters to consist of a single uppercase letter each, e.g., `EntityRepository<E extends Entity>`. Using what looks like an actual type name, `Entidade`, as a generics parameter makes it very hard indeed to figure out which the symbol represents at different times - is it a generics parameter or a type? Your cooperation helps everyone (including yourself) help you.

Comment: @Radiodef The problem is not with the `create` method and the `Entity` item it receives, but with the `EntityRepository<? extends Entity> repository` argument of the `subMenu` method instead.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I'm well aware of why this error happens. However, I've looked at the code for `subMenu` and observed that OP intends to pass several different types of `Entity` to `create` such that the only type argument which would fulfill this requirement is equivalent to the upper bound of `Entidade`, which makes the generics pointless.

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, I agree with you on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should stick to naming conventions regarding generic type parameters, which state that they should consist of a single capital letter. So let's change your code accordingly:

```
public class EntityRepository<E extends Entity> {
    // code
}
```

Now, your problem consists of a misunderstanding of the [PECS principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). In short, **PECS** stands for **P**roducer **E**xtends **C**onsumer **S**uper.

It means that if a parameterized type, i.e. `EntityRepository` *produces* a type that matches the type of its parameter, i.e. `Entity`, you should use the keyword `extends`. By *produces* I mean that one or more methods of the parameterized type return a value whose type is the type of the generic parameter. In your example, in the `subMenu` method, if `EntityRepository` had a method that returns a *descendant* of `Entity` (which is its generic type parameter), then it would be a producer.

On the contrary, if a parameterized type, i.e. `EntityRepository` *consumes* a type that matches the type of its parameter, i.e. `Entity`, you should use the keyword `super`. By *consumes* I mean that one or more methods of the parameterized type receive one or more arguments whose type is the type of the generic parameter. In your example, in the `subMenu` method, if `EntityRepository` had a method that accepts a *descendant* (yes, a descendant!) of `Entity` (which is its generic type parameter), then it would be a consumer.

Now, within the `subMenu` method, you are invoking the `EntityRepository.create` method, which receives an `Entity` as an argument, so, according to the PECS principle, the signature of your `subMenu` method should be:

```
public static void subMenu(EntityRepository<? super Entity> repository, String entidade)
```

which means that, within the scope of the `subMenu` method, `EntityRepository` is a consumer of `Entity`.

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine but the use of `? super Entity` just illustrates what I was talking about in my other comments. Our upper bound of `E` is declared as `Entity` and now we've bounded it with a lower bound of `Entity` as well, so there is only one type which fulfills both constraints: `Entity`. In other words, `subMenu` can only ever be called with an `EntityRepository<Entity>`.

Comment: first of all thanks for all the comments. really :D
and second, ill try to make my code better with the upper case letters.

now im pretty sure that i want to use `extends` and not `super` cause I beleave its the same as`integer` extends to `number` as my `entity` would be same as `number`.

when i rename to `? super Entity`, my `subMenu` calls will give an error as there is nothing superior to `Entity`, except maybe `Object`.

Comment: @Nunomoreira Well, if I use `EntityRepository<? extends Entity> repository` the code does not compile, specifically the line `repository.create(item);` in the `subMenu` method throws an error. When I change it to `EntityRepository<? super Entity> repository`, everything works fine. However, when you try to invoke your `subMenu` method with i.e. an `EntityRepository<Product>` the code does not compile. And it's fine that it doesn't, because you might be calling `subMenu` with an `EntityRepository<Product>` and the string `"prateleira"`.

Comment: @Nunomoreira If you did that, inside the `subMenu` method, you would end up calling `create` on the passed `repository` (which is an `EntityRepository<Product>`) with an argument of type `Shelf`. This is why the compiler complains. So IMHO all this indicates that you should carefully rethink your design. Question... Why aren't both `Entity` and `EntityRepository` abstract? Besides, why are you creating the concrete entity outside the repo? i.e. in your `subMenu` method. And most important, why are you creating the concrete entity based on a string parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! the prolem was solved. It was my fault as i didnt described it as i should. im new to this xD

anyway thanks!